# Trying to charge before or after Subscription Schedule is created Stripe API

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I am developing a wordpress website for a client.
He needs different types of packages. For most of these packages I developed a simple Stripe checkout webpage, using its documentation.
The problem is that I need this workflow:

- first month x dollars
- second month x dollars
- after one year subscription y dollars

I've already done this using Subscription Schedule. But it needs a customer ofc. How can I charge before and after charging create this Subscription Schedule? I don't know how to deal with this, how to charge using Stripe checkout simple already built page or do I need to create one by myself, where user needs to add his card, pay, and get the customer_id?

```
    function checkout3() {
    // Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51e7DRPLRnISGb5vSFxnvvuDx1GzhlBIFeazcmpEevsUFf29jHXJ1YgE2xaJ1lGfzjtKzE8uoN0eR9Klaq00CnMFWvfB');
    
    // The price ID passed from the front end.
    //   $priceId = $_POST['priceId'];
    $priceId = 'price_1LPahmIne7DRPLRnFXV6Uz34';
    
   $futureDate= strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year')));

   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(
       [
          'description' => 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs at https://www.stripe.com/docs/api)',
          
        ]
       );
       
 
   $session = \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::create([
      'customer' => $customer["id"],
      'start_date' => 'now',
      'end_behavior' => 'release',
      'phases' => [
        [
          'items' => [
            [
              'price' => 'price_1LRF5CIne7DRPLRnwuLVE2pu',
              'quantity' => 1,
            ],
          ],
          //'end_date' => $futureDate,
          'iterations' => 1,
        ],
        [
          'items' => [
            [
              'price' => 'price_1LRF5cIne7DRPLRngevvIZiw',
              'quantity' => 1,
            ],
          ],
          'iterations' => 1,
        ],
        [
          'items' => [
            [
              'price' => 'price_1LPujQIne7DRPLRnj3EOweJN',
              'quantity' => 1,
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ]);
    
    // Redirect to the URL returned on the Checkout Session.
    // With vanilla PHP, you can redirect with:
       //header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
       //header("Location: " . '$session->url');
}
```

So right now, the subscription schedule is added to the Stripe dashboard, the page it's keep loading infinitely, but without charging... How to deal with this?

```
  public static function firebase_checkout3_func() {
        $html = "";
        $html .= "<form id='firebase-checkout' action='/wp-json/api/checkout2' method='POST'>
                    <button type='submit' id='checkout-button'>Începe acum</button>
                </form>";
        return $html;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Stripe hosted Checkout Page with `setup` mode to [collect
   a Customer's SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=checkout)
2. Retrieve the [Payment Method inside the SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object#setup_intent_object-payment_method)
3. Set it as the customer's [invoice_settings.default_payment_method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-invoice_settings-default_payment_method)
4. Create a Subscription Schedule with that Customer Id as normal

Comment: If I add then a subscription schedule with customer id, won't be 2 subscriptions? or the first one will automatically cancel?

Comment: What do you mean by 2 subscriptions? In this flow (step 4) you only create a Subscription Schedule, so it's 1 subscription in the end

Comment: Oh ok, so the subscription schedule is only updating the subscription, it's not a subscription itself. I mean, it's possible to create the subsription schedule directly  with subscription id, after creating the subscription and then update it.

Comment: Just for clarify, I need to set the start date for step 4 to a future date, like after 1 month or 1 year, right? Because the first payment was made already.

Comment: I tested and setup mode isn't create any pament, but I need to show them immediately after checkout a sucess page, so I created a checkout session subscription mode and after that create a subscription schedule with delayed start time.

Comment: re: I need to set the start date for step 4 to a future date, no. You can backdate if you want. See Subscription Schedule use cases: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases

re: setup mode isn't create any pament, yes it's how SetupIntent or Checkout w Setup mode works, it only collects PaymentMethod beforehand without actually making any payment.

Comment: If you created a Checkout Session subscription mode then create a delayed Subscription Schedule *from that Subscription* then it could work yes, but need to be careful with proration.